# Динамический фильтр

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Есть таблица

| CLIENT | RN | DP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 |
| 4 | 1 | 9 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 | 5 |

Нужно отфильтровать по колонке `rn` записи с значением 2 если же их нет тогда 1

Желаемый результат

| CLIENT | RN | DP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 8 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 |

Фильтр таблиц я делаю внутренним запросом `where rn in (...)`
Но как реализовать динамический подход ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> записи с значением 2 если же их нет тогда 1

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       client,
       MAX(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY client) AS rn,
       FIRST_VALUE(dp) OVER (PARTITION BY client ORDER BY rn DESC) dp
FROM table
WHERE rn IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что хотел